# Bar-chart gradient background not showing - Highcharts

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, highcharts

I am using Highcharts.js-library to create a bar-chart at my website and I would like to have a gradient as background-color (fill) of the bars. I have done it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/19u1w0wk/13/) in JSFiddle and everything is working fine. But when I use the same code at my website, it is not working and I can't figure out why.

My js-code is like this:

```
$(function () {

    Highcharts.chart('container', {

        title: {
            text: ''
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Driftsinntekter forrige år', 'Resultat før skatt forrige år', 'Egenkapital', 'Driftsresultat', 'Årsresultat']
        },

        defs: {
            gradient0: {
                tagName: 'linearGradient',
                id: 'gradient-0',
                x1: 0,
                y1: 0,
                x2: 0,
                y2: 1,
                children: [{
                    tagName: 'stop',
                    offset: 0
                }, {
                    tagName: 'stop',
                    offset: 1
                }]
            }, glow: {
                tagName: 'filter',
                id: 'glow',
                opacity: 0.5,
                children: [{
                    tagName: 'feGaussianBlur',
                    result: 'coloredBlur',
                    stdDeviation: 1.5
                }, {
                    tagName: 'feMerge',
                    children: [{
                        tagName: 'feMergeNode',
                        in: 'coloredBlur'
                    }, {
                        tagName: 'feMergeNode',
                        in: 'SourceGraphic'
                    }]
                }]
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'bar',
            keys: ['y', 'selected'],
            data: [
                [29.9, false],
                [71.5, false],
                [106.4, false],
                [129.2, false],
                [144.0, false]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

And my CSS is like this (its in a separate file):

```
@import 'https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css';

#container {
    height: 400px;
    max-width: 800px;
    min-width: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Define the stop colors */
#gradient-0 stop {
    stop-color: #DBFDFC;
}
#gradient-0 stop[offset="0"] {
    stop-opacity: 1;
}
#gradient-0 stop[offset="1"] {
    stop-color: #2E3D50;
}

/* Apply the gradients */
.highcharts-point-select, .highcharts-color-0 {
  filter: url('#glow');
  stroke: transparent;
    fill-opacity: 1;
    fill: url('#gradient-0');
}
```

[Here](http://www.firma-info.no/bedrift/dahls-data-as) is the live-page - if you scroll down to "Regnskap"-section you will see the chart-grid but no bars. If you use the web-dev-tool you can see that there is a bar at "Driftsinntekter forrige år" but it is just not showing.

I am including the library and the css-file in `head`-tag as following:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/charts.css">
```

Hope somebody can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There seem to be a problem in your url to your fill and filter:

    ```fill: url(#gradient-0);```
    ```filter: url(#glow);```

Answer (score 0):

Now its working. My problem was that I was including the wrong Highcharts-mode in `head`-tag.

I had to include this one (styled mode):

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/js/highcharts.js"></script>
```